# Is the transmission of confidential data through json secure? laravel 7 -digital certificate signature

Tags: php, json, laravel

I need to sign documents, but for that I need to pass the password and the certificate path via json

is it really safe to use this?
how could i implement these arrays in a php configuration file?
so that nobody (external public) has access to the data, I know that php can do that.

---

I am configuring an api that has the following in its documentation:

> Configuring the API The API configuration is done through a file or
> even an array in JSON format.
>
> This JSON array contains the data necessary for the API to know where
> important files are, such as digital certificates and other relevant
> information.

```
{"atualizacao":"2016-02-02 08:01:21","tpAmb":2,"pathXmlUrlFileNFe":"nfe_ws3_mod55.xml","pathXmlUrlFileCTe":"cte_ws1.xml","pathXmlUrlFileMDFe":"mdfe_ws1.xml","pathXmlUrlFileCLe":"cle_ws1.xml","pathXmlUrlFileNFSe":"","pathNFeFiles":"/MyApp/nfe","pathCTeFiles":"/MyApp/cte","pathMDFeFiles":"/MyApp/mdfe","pathCLeFiles":"/MyApp/cle","pathNFSeFiles":"/MyApp/nfse","pathCertsFiles":"/MyApp/certs/","siteUrl":"http://myapp.local","schemesNFe":"PL_008h2","schemesCTe":"PL_CTE_104","schemesMDFe":"MDFe_100","schemesCLe":"CLe_100","schemesNFSe":"","razaosocial":"Fulano de tal Ltda","siglaUF":"AM","cnpj":"547678524000133","tokenIBPT":"AAAAAAA","tokenNFCe":"GPB0JBWLUR6HWFTVEAS6RJ69GPCROFPBBB8G","tokenNFCeId":"000002","certPfxName":"myapp_2016.pfx","certPassword":"JIO&$@2990_zx","certPhrase":"tajomstvo","aDocFormat":{"format":"P","paper":"A4","southpaw":"1","pathLogoFile":"/MyApp/publico/images/logo.jpg","logoPosition":"L","font":"Times","printer":"hpteste"},"aMailConf":{"mailAuth":"1","mailFrom":"roberto@myapp.local","mailSmtp":"smtp.myapp.local","mailUser":"roberto@myapp.local","mailPass":"heslo$","mailProtocol":"ssl","mailPort":"587","mailFromMail":null,"mailFromName":null,"mailReplayToMail":null,"mailReplayToName":null,"mailImapHost":null,"mailImapPort":null,"mailImapSecurity":null,"mailImapNocerts":null,"mailImapBox":null},"aProxyConf":{"proxyIp":"","proxyPort":"","proxyUser":"","proxyPass":""}}
```

The documentation doesn't show how to implement it, it just shows the example of json array, which can also be done in a php file, I suppose I should put that array in something like config.json and call it in the controller, I don't know how it would be this call and where i would put it, i can place it anywhere, but my biggest concern is with the need to put personal fingers as passwords in this matrix, json is a file that can be accessed by anyone via browser, I don't know whether it is appropriate and safe to implement as they are suggesting.
Would this really be the best practice?

Comment: show your documents, i dont understand exactly what you ask

Comment: Sorry to delay to answer you! Basically, I'm asking two questions, the laravel package that manages the API indicates that the configuration is done through the json file, but you need to put confidential data there, and json is a public file; if you access it directly, you will see the content as text

Comment: is it really safe to use this?
how could i implement these arrays in a php configuration file? so that nobody (external public) has access to the data, I know that php can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're posting it over https you should be fine and it's not unlike a bearer token. If you include anything in the query string that would be recorded in things like access logs, etc.

Edit: for any question about security, it does depend on how far down the rabbit hole you want to go. POST/PUTing data is more secure than using GET becuase of how it gets processed by the server. But from the question becomes how secure is your server, your ssl setup, etc. So you end up weighing how secure it needs to be based on the importance of the data remaining secure.

Comment: well, more and if you find out where the json file is, it would be very easy, wouldn't it?
see what happened to the video app called zoom. the password will be in the array

Comment: The way most frameworks handle this is all of your configuration files are stored outside of your public directory. For instance, Laravel has all of its files one level above /public, and only the /public folder is accesible to the public. Storing sensitive data like credentials is necessary for the function of any project. However, you still dont want to store more than you need to, and to encrypt things that should never be seen by anyone, not even the project author, like user passwords. My answer is more relevant to how to "send" secure data, not necessarily store it.

Comment: yes, but I did a test here and found that if I go to myapp.com/config, it shows error 403, but if I go straight to the point and put myapp.com/config/my.json, it will show the content, it is because they believe that the php will not show anything; therefore, all folders are public; if you know where it is and if it is not a php file, you can get there.

Comment: an htaccess would solve, but I think that this can hinder the laravel

Comment: @Macedo_Montalvão for Laravel, the sensitive files are above your public folder. Anything not in within the public folder is prviate unless made accessible through controllers, etc.

Comment: Not so ... try to put a file inside the APP, CONFIG or any other folder, you can access the file if you go straight to it, for example: myapp.com/config/about.html.
 If you only access myapp.com/config/ it will show you 403 error, but if you go straight to the file, it will be displayed! one way out can be to put the laravel in a folder not accessible via the browser, although this makes things more difficult. this is a security breach of laravel, it may be particular to the new version.

Comment: remembering that it is not necessary to place the laravel private folders outside the htdocs folder, as the fremework itself proposes to filter the routes and protect the folders, although this is missing from the official package that I downloaded by the composer. It seems that the new version is unstable to implement in production mode.

Comment: @Macedo_Montalvão that's absolutely not the case and there are thousands of sites using it for production. In most cases people provision with laravel forge or envoyer and its taken care of automatically. And these stacks use nginx, not apache. If you were to use apache, you could simply make sure all of your laravel files rest above public_html.